# fast alternative to grep file multiple times?

Tags: bash, text, grep

I currently use long piped `bash` commands to extract data from text files like this, where *$f* is my file:

```
result=$(grep "entry t $t " $f | cut -d ' ' -f 5,19 | \
         sort -nk2 | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
```

I use a script that might do hundreds of similar searches of *$f* ,sorting selected lines in various ways depending on what I'm pulling out. I like one-line `bash` strings with a bunch of *pipes* because its compact and easy, but it can take forever. Can anyone suggest a faster alternative? Maybe something that loads the whole file into memory first?

Thanks

Comment: you're right: it's slow and will continue to be because grep reads from disk, and also searches lines linearly. Looks like you're ready for python and its dictionaries... If you posted a [mcve] with your code, a sample input and expected output, I may come up with something.

Comment: before that, you could prepare sub-lists with pre-grepped patterns so searches in those sub-lists will be faster.

Comment: Hard to say till you provide concrete examples of how your files look and what you are trying to achieve and what your machine is like. Maybe parallel searches with GNU Parallel, maybe `awk`, maybe `Perl`. Your question is very broad.

Comment: What's `$t`? I have a horrible feeling you're executing that command line in a loop for multiple values of `t`. As already recommended - post a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output or you're likely to get a solution that might be faster than what you have but is still orders of magnitude slower and probably more complex than it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You might get a boost with doing the whole pipe with `gawk` or another `awk` that has `asorti` by doing:

```
contents="$(cat "$f")"
result="$(awk -vpattern="entry t $t" '$0 ~ pattern {matches[$5]=$19} END {asorti(matches,inds); print inds[1]}' <<<"$contents")"
```

This will read "$f" into a variable then we'll use a single `awk` command (well, `gawk` anyway) to do all the rest of the work.  Here's how that works:

- **-vpattern="entry t $t"**: defines an `awk` variable named `pattern` that contains the shell variable `t`
- **$0 ~ pattern** matches the current line against the pattern, if it matches we'll do the part in the braces, otherwise we skip it

  - **matches[$5]=$19** adds an entry to an array (and creates the array if needed) where the key is the 5th field and the value is the 19th
- **END** do the following function after all the input has been processed

  - **asorti(matches,inds)** sort the entries of `matches` such that the `inds` is an array holding the order of the keys in `matches` to get the values in sorted order
  - **print inds[1]** prints the index in matches (i.e., a $5 from before) associated with the lowest 19th field
- **<<<"$contents"** have `awk` work on the value in the shell variable `contents` as though it were a file it was reading

Then you can just update the pattern for each, not have to read the file from disk each time and not need so many extra processes for all the pipes.

You'll have to benchmark to see if it's really faster or not though, and if performance is important you really should think about moving to a "proper" language instead of shell scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided sample input/output this is just a guess and I only post it because there's other answers already posted that you should not do, so - this may be what you want instead of that one line:

```
result=$(awk -v t="$t" '
    BEGIN { regexp = "entry t " t " " }
    $0 ~ regexp {
        if ( ($6 > maxKey) || (maxKey == "") ) {
            maxKey = $6
            maxVal = $5
        }
    }
    END { print maxVal }
' "$f")
```

I suspect your real performance issue, however, isn't that script but that you are running it and maybe others inside a loop that you haven't shown us. If so, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and post a better example so we can help you.